# capybara-webkit: automatically save a screenshot on an RSpec test failure

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, capybara

How can I automatically save the html and a screenshot when a test fails using capybara-webkit with Rspec? How can I execute a callback when an RSpec test fails.

Bonus points: how can I avoid getting the following error:

```
Capybara::Driver::Webkit::WebkitInvalidResponseError
```

when executing this code:

```
require 'capybara/util/save_and_open_page'
path = "/#{Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')}"
png = Capybara.save_and_open_page_path + "#{path}.png"
page.driver.render Rails.root.join(png)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a gist that might help you https://gist.github.com/1156691

Comment: 1) it is for cucumber, which I am not using. 2) I get above error

Comment: Not sure about the error but you can create an after each block in rspec that checks if the test has passed. Rspec provides an @exception instance variable, just check if it is present.

Answer (score 18):

I have written a gem Capybara-Screenshot specifically for this, check out https://github.com/mattheworiordan/capybara-screenshot

It will automatically create screen shots on failed RSpec or Cucumber steps.

Comment: Or you can put `save_and_open_screenshot` without a new gem, at least now :)

Comment: @Aleks I upvoted your new answer - we can delete our comments now

Answer (score 4):

Capybara provides a function for saving and opening a screenshoot during the testing. You just need to call anywhere in your test:

`save_and_open_screenshot`

and it will open a picture how the test looks like at that point.
No need for any additional gems.

[Capybara::save_and_open_screenshot](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Session:save_and_open_screenshot)