# save_and_open_page not working with capybara 2.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capybara

I just had my capybara updated to 2.0, and all of my save_and_open_page calls return an html page without styling.  It has the style sheets links properly at the top of the page.  When I revert back to capybara 1.3, the styles work again.  Anyone know how to fix this, and/or what the problem is?

thanks,
Dave

---

Update 1.

hack:

I have found a reasonable way to get around the problem following the links recommended by simonmorley:
[Capybara Webkit problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802614/capybara-webkit-automatically-save-a-screenshot-on-an-rspec-test-failure?rq=1)
which points to: [capybara-screenshot](https://github.com/mattheworiordan/capybara-screenshot)

It involves using the capybara-screenshot gem to get a screenshot of what the page looks like.  When you combine it with the save_and_open_page, which generates the html, you can see what it looks like, and see the HTML.

```
    save_and_open_page
    Capybara::Screenshot.screenshot_and_open_image
```

If I could get `Capybara::Screenshot.screenshot_and_save_page` to work, then I think that I might have a solution (if the name implies the action I think it does).  However, when I try it, I get `cannot load such file -- capybara/util/save_and_open_page`

---

Update 2.

!! wait, the screenshot_and_open_image is not working now (no png image created or displayed).  !!

---

Update 3.

**Test App:**

I created a test app, and posted it at [test_capybara_screenshot on Github](https://github.com/tayloredwebsites/test_capybara_screenshot).

When I run this test app in development, the page come up with the blaring red background style displayed.  When I run the tests, the only thing that works for me is the save_and_open_page, except there is no styling.

Note, when I run any tests, I get the following warning:

> WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.7.8, but has dynamically loaded 2.7.3

**Details of the rspec test:**

- The save_and_open_page comes up with a boring white background (no
  styling).
- the screenshot_and_open_image returns with the error:

> Rack::Test capybara driver has no ability to output screen shots. Skipping.
>
> Failure in opening /~/Documents/experiments/test_capybara_screenshot/tmp/capybara/screenshot-2012-11-26-07-48-29.png with options {}: No application found to handle '/~/Documents/experiments/test_capybara_screenshot/tmp/capybara/screenshot-2012-11-26-07-48-29.png'

- The screenshot_and_save_page returns:

> An error occurred in an after hook
>
> LoadError: cannot load such file -- capybara/util/save_and_open_page
> occurred at ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'

---

Comment: Do you have launchy installed??

Comment: I don't think you should get styles, because the CSS links will be broken.

Comment: What does that mean "the CSS links will be broken"?

Comment: Your CSS links will all be in the format `/assets/blah.css`, and when you save and open the page it opens a raw HTML file from your tmp folder... what CSS files should it be pointing to?

Comment: There is a difference in the CSS links.  The 1.3 links point to the css file using the full disk path, followed by the querystring version number.  The 2.0 link is relative from the public directory. Note, this app was generated pre asset pipeline.

Comment: It is 2017 and I still have this problem. The only thing working from all answers is the `js: true` hack

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem with save_and_open_page after some blog browsing and digging.  I have dropped the capybara_screenshot gem from my project.  You can see my working code on my [github test_capybara_screenshot repository](https://github.com/tayloredwebsites/test_capybara_screenshot).  The solution that I figured out uses some pointers that I found on the [capybara github site](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/pull/500).

Assumptions:

- You are using rspec for testing.
- Your app is already configured for using the asset pipeline.

The first thing that I do is set it up so that assets are precompiled into a test directory.  I do this by adding the following code into the `spec/spec_helper.rb` file within the `RSpec.configure` loop:

```
config.before (scope = :suite) do
  %x[bundle exec rake assets:precompile]
end
```

I specify where the assets are pre-compiled to in the `config/environments/test.rb` file:

```
config.assets.prefix = "assets_test"    # place test assets in public/assets_test directory
config.action_controller.asset_host = "file://#{::Rails.root}/public"
```

This makes it so that the test assets are independent of the development assets, and are only generated during a test suite run.

If you do this, you will probably want to have git ignore the `/public/assets*` directories.

Comment: Even though I have save_and_open_page working to display now, I still have a problem with the values that are filled in beforehand.  In 1.1.3, the filled in values are shown, but in 2.0, only the original values are shown.

Comment: Why do you place the assets in `public/assets_test`, but set the asset_host to `/public`? Shouldn't it be  `public/assets_test`?

Answer (score 27):

Try adding the following to your gem file

```
group :test do
  gem "capybara"
  gem "launchy"
end
```

save_and_open_page won't work without this I don't believe.

-- Updated --

I've tested this for you and when I used the save and open method, I get the same error. In my set up, this is because my page is referencing:

```
<link href="/assets/application.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

This happens in Firefox, Chrome and Safari. According to the inspector, none of the files are found.

I haven't looked into this in too much detail and don't have an answer why it's not working. However there are a number of people struggling with this also:

https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/485

And, a bit more information about capybara and asset precompilation:

https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/pull/609

And what might be a fix here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ruby-capybara/SBCor8UUj7w/hv97EgUQ1P4J

However, if you just want to see your page you could try this: delete scrap save_and_open_page and change your tests to use javascript. This way, my pages open fine.

```
 require 'spec_helper'

 describe "Foo" do
   it "should fail if Bar is lactose intolerant", :js => true do
     # .....
   end
 end
```

Try that and let me know if that helps.

---

response (From Taylored Web Sites):

I see the page for a few seconds, then it goes away.  Is there a way for the browser window to not close?

Comment: Thats how I got it to work originally.  I still have not removed launchy.

Comment: Did anything else get updated? I think sevenseacat might be correct - you need to check the paths. If you're able to test in firefox, you could check if that gets they styling when the tests run.

Comment: When I look at the page generated, firefox lists the css file, and says there are no rules.

Comment: No rules? Do you mean no css in the file? You don't get a 404?

Comment: You can see the filename in the dropdown of CSS files, and there is no 404.

Comment: Just running my own capybara tests. Will see if I can replicate.

Comment: I don't know what your requirements are. Sometimes we sleep for a bit. However, I guess you could try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802614/capybara-webkit-automatically-save-a-screenshot-on-an-rspec-test-failure?rq=1

Comment: I have gotten a partial solution from this suggestion from you, as I mention in my edit of the question.  I could not get the Capybara::Screenshot.screenshot_and_save_page to work (I get an error cannot load such file -- capybara/util/save_and_open_page, and requiring it does not seem to work).

Comment: Have you read through the links I put in my post? It seems there's a problem with asset pre-compilation and there's a few suggestions about how to fix there. Good luck, S

Comment: I could not follow the chats very well.  I am guessing the asset pipeline patch is not relevant to me, since I am using static assets.  I know nothing about the capybara asset server, and how I might be able to take advantage of it, or how to patch it if it is broken.

Comment: Sounds like you've got it working. If you're not getting the file, make sure you're specifying the file name and path. One of the links I sent had instructions. S

Comment: I don''t know what happened, but the screenshot_and_open_image is not working anymore, so I am back where I started.

Comment: try to add gem 'rb-fsevent'

Comment: +10 to the ":js => true" hint. It unblocked me after many hours of search. It's a workaround rather than a solution, but at least I can figure out where my bug is.