# Capybara::ElementNotFound error when for xpath

Tags: ruby, xpath, cucumber, capybara

I'm running into an issue where I'm running the following capybara/cucumber code:

```
When /^I click the neighborhood link from map view$/  do
  find(:xpath, './/*[@id="resultWrapper"]').click
  find(:xpath, './/*[@id="result_158906"]/div[2]/span/a[1]').click
end
```

But I get the following error in cucumber:

```
When I click the neighborhood link from map view                  
Unable to find xpath ".//*[@id=\"resultWrapper\"]" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
```

In irb, I can perform those previous `find` commands, and it will return with a "ok" response.  But in my ruby code it will fail everytime.  I've tried everything to figure this out and no dice.  Any suggestions would be nice, thanks!!

Comment: Are you sure the element is actually there? It might be constructed and runtime using JavaScript and thus missing in the original HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using launchy and capybara screenshot to see what page you're actually on.  See this thread:

[save_and_open_page not working with capybara 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484808/save-and-open-page-not-working-with-capybara-2-0)

You could also drop a debugger and look at

```
page.html
```

To see what the actually HTML on the current page is.